# CSS position object relative to document

Tags: css, html, positioning

When i try to position this div (which is used as a image) relatively to the document, it doesn't show up however if i position it :absolute it works is there any way around this?

```
   #headr {
        background-image:url(../images/top%20bg.jpg);
        height:50%;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
}

    <body>

<div id="headr">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a external stylesheet? Or if it's a internal stylesheet are you wrapping the style tag properly? Please show a fiddle if you can.

Comment: remove spacing between top""20bg.jpg, this is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

you must add `position: relative;` to the body if you want to position something relative within it. Positioning things relative only works if a parent container is positioned relative, fixed or absolute (not static which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

If #headr has no contents, it won't have height. Height percentages only work when the parent has a fixed height. Otherwise, you need to use a static height, like px or em...

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/Vx669/)

CSS:

```
#headr {
    background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/200/100");
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #bada55;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="headr">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give position:relative to the parent div and position:absolute to his child (div)

Comment: That won't change the fact that this div has 0 height (or if it has any, it won't be the expected 50%).